# How to trigger an event in the parent page from the included page in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, listener

I have the `parent.xhtml` page in which I've included a `child.xhtml` page.
In the child page I have a button and upon clicking it I want to trigger a listener/action event in the parent page (let's say I want to execute a method from the parent's bean).

**Edit**: I need to make the child page as atomic as possible so it can be reused in other parents/wrappers too. That would mean to simply make it broadcast an event which can be listened by whoever will be the parent page.

parent.xhtml:

```
<ui:include src="/content/childPage.xhtml"></ui:include>
```

child.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton doSomething....>
</p:commandButton>
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 6, JSF 2.

Comment: do you want to send let say some Data from the `parent.xhtml` to the `child.xhtml` or in the other way ?!?

Comment: because in the first way you can add some informations to your include and change a little bit the structure of your `child.xhtml`

Comment: hey! I want to send from child to parent. The child.xhtml is in another jar.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two 'pages' are client-side just one html page. So you can have a very simple 'event' based solution where you combine the [PrimeFaces remoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) with jquery event handling

In the client.xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Click me" onclick="$(document).trigger("myevent");" />
```

In the parent.xhtml:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("myevent", rc);
</script>

<p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="msgs" actionListener="#{parentViewBean.execute}" />
```

The parent can then fully and easily define what action to call. The downside is that if you have no 'event' handler in the parent, the button does not seem to do anything. If that is a problem, that can be solved to.

Change the client.xhtml to:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Click me" onclick="fireEventIfPresent" />

<script>
function fireEventIfPresent() {
    if($._data(document, "events")['myevent']) { // check if eventhandler is present
        $(document).trigger("myevent");         
    } else {
        alert('No event handler in parent page');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I always appreciate people taking the time to read my answers (or comments) and judge them. Would appreciate it though if with technically correct answers, downvotes are accompanied by an explanation. That way, I can either improve it or learn from it for future answers

Answer (score -1):

To send data information from the `child.xhtml` to your your `parent.xhtml` you have to add a `ManagedProperty` to the `ChildManagedBean` referring your `ParentManagedBean`.

**ChildManagedBean.java**

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{parentManagedBean}")
private ParentManagedBean e;
```

Now let see this from the `child.xhtml`

**child.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton actionListner="#{childManagedBean.doSomething()}"....>
</p:commandButton>
```

**ChildManagedBean.java**

```
public void doSomething(){
    Boolean test = Boolean.TRUE;
    e.methodGetInfof(test);
}
```

To make it reusable you have to add this to your `parent.xhtml`

**parent.xhtml**

```
<ui:include src="/content/childPage.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="action" value="executeMethod"/>
    <ui:param name="bean" value="#{ManagedBean}" />
</ui:include>
```

and add this to your `child.xhtml`

**child.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bean[action]()}"....>
</p:commandButton>
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: I have a button in the child. When I click the button I want to trigger an event in the parent. I don't want to send anything from the parent to the child.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I want to be able to reuse the child page in other pages too.

Comment: I think that you have to ask an other question. and if this answer was the right answer make it the answer for this question

Comment: This only resolves a part of the problem. I must not explicitly refer to the parent from the child as it would not be standalone/atomic anymore. I've updated the question to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion this solution is unnecessarily  complex and indeed  is not loosly coupling things